# Need driver for Panasonic KX-MB1520

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, printing

Recently, I purchased Panasonic KX-MB 1520 All-in-one laser printer with FAX. I have installation CD with me but it is available only for Microsoft Windows OS. 
Please provide its drivers and help me install this printer on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

or time being (urgent makeshift solution)
Please tell me ... if I install wine and run installation/driver cd will it work?

Answer (score 0):

This software is Panasonic Printer Driver for Linux.
You can print from applications by using CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) which is the printing system for Linux.

http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html